# Codeigniter copying the entire file, new cannot get the controller function (needs index.php)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CI file that named pos and I got a backup named pos2 copied from the orginal pos, i tried to run the pos2, I already changed the config base_url from pos to pos2, now the thing is once i run a function from the controller, it says
404 Page Not Found, my original pos doesnt require index.php so that means when I run the function mywebsite.com/pos/Authentication/login it works in pos but in pos2 it doesnt, so i tried mywebsite.com/pos2/index.php/Authentication/login and it worked, my question is how can i remove the index.php in the pos2 when it has the same structure in pos?

Comment: So where is your htaccess file you are using for pos and what is in it?

Comment: <IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

Comment: So you are saying that is the .htaccess file you are using to remove index.php from the URL? I disbelieve :)